# Why some data is removed with the command to_csv()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, export-to-csv

I have generated a dataset df :

input :

`print(df)`

output :

```
              time_tweet       time_stock     sentiment   trend
0    2019-02-26 18:08:14  2019-02-26 18:09:00  positive    DOWN
1    2019-02-25 23:17:02  2019-02-25 23:18:00  positive    DOWN
2    2019-02-25 23:12:25  2019-02-25 23:13:00  positive      UP
3    2019-02-25 22:08:57  2019-02-25 22:09:00  negative    DOWN
...            ...                 ...           ...        ...
```

To stock my data on my computer I use the command :

```
df.to_csv("Desktop/results.csv")
```

When I consult the data directly on my CSV file (results.csv) on my desktop I get :

[image: results.csv]

As you can see, the seconds are removed in the columns "time_tweet" and "time_stock".

Could you tell me why ?

Comment: If check in some text editor like notepad++ same problem?

Comment: I just checked it with notepad++ and the seconds are not remove in this text editor. Thank you a lot for this answer. But do you know why it doesn't appear on CSV file?

Comment: As I can see you opened this in excel and excel interprets the format of your columns. In this case it converted your datetime format to `DD.MM.YY hh:mm`. This is not a pandas or python problem. Open the csv in notepad++ or other text editor and you will see the original data.

Comment: change the value format in your spreadsheet to show the seconds part. excel detects your time stamps and guesses that you want to see the data up to the minute.

Comment: A CSV file should **never** be tested in Excel. If it is good in notepad++ and bad in Excel, it is a formatting problem in Excel. *The seconds are removed in the CSV* is a wrong diagnostic that is likely to disturb readers of the question. The correct diagnostic would be *the seconds are not displayed in Excel*. And the answer to that question is just *check the display format in Excel*